# How can I use value of the id column as default value of another non-nullable column when using postgresql-rails?

Tags: postgresql, rails

Here's one example where such a requirement comes up:

Suppose we have a table 'sample' in our database which has a column 'col1' and an auto-incremental 'id' column. We want the default value of 'col1' to be taken as the value of the 'id' column. How do I do that?

I am using rails to write the migration script which will create the table in my postgres databse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to manually create your own [sequence](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-sequence.html) instead of letting Postgres/Rails do it for you. Then, because you know the name of the sequence you can use `currval()` to grab the current value of `id` as the `DEFAULT` value for other rows.

In a Rails migration, you can drop down to raw SQL for this:

```
class CreateSampleTable < ActiveRecord::Migration

  def up

    execute "CREATE SEQUENCE sample_id_seq"

    execute %{
      CREATE TABLE sample (
        id   bigint UNIQUE NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('sample_id_seq'),
        col1 bigint        NOT NULL DEFAULT currval('sample_id_seq')
        -- Add other columns here
      )
    }

    execute "ALTER SEQUENCE sample_id_seq OWNED BY sample.id"

  end

  def down
    drop_table :sample
  end

end
```

Now whenever you insert a row into this table, `id` will auto-increment and `col1` will have the same value as `id` by default.

Comment: This was helpful.
Can this logic be executed using the `change` syntax available in recent version of rails?

Comment: `change` is shorthand for `up`/`down` ( `change` will attempt to automatically implement an opposing `down` method for you). Using `execute` prevents the shorthand. `up` and `down` are still available for just this reason.